# MDT - Storage driver injection, do you need to rebuild windows image?

Tags: drivers, mdt-2012

I'm trying to install an image to a machine. I keep getting storage driver errors where it can't find the hard drives. That's fine, so I went and got the drivers and added them. I regenerated the boot image completely. Do I need to do another sysprep or should I be able to get by with just injecting the drivers into the boot image (i.e., regenerating the boot image)?

I also checked the inf file to make sure the proper device ID shows up in there compared to the RAID device ID and it's in there. Still doesn't seem to recognize it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need the drivers in the boot image and the install image.

There's no need to recapture an image if you're just adding drivers or Windows Updates, though. You can use `dism.exe` to add drivers and updates to an offline wim file. This process is [documented on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744355(v=ws.10).aspx).

Here are the basics. Obviously modify them for your own enviroment:

```
Dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:C:\test\images\install.wim /Name:"Windows 7 Enterprise" /MountDir:C:\test\offline

Dism /Image:C:\test\offline /Add-Driver /Driver:C:\drivers\mydriver.INF

Dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:C:\test\offline /Commit
```

This way you can integrate new drivers into an image without wasting a rearm and spending all of that time doing an install, update, sysprep, and capture.

Comment: Completely forgot about that. Not sure why it doesn't recognize this driver, but I'm going to create a basic WindowsPE disc and see if I can add the driver to it. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt that's not what I meant. What I was saying was that you need to add the driver to your install image as well as the boot image. My post was saying that you don't need to do a capture/sysprep to do that.

Comment: yea, I know. I'm just trying to troubleshoot as to why it won't find this certain driver. It takes longer to regenerate the boot image than to just create a windowsPE disc with the drivers and test it.

Comment: so, would you know why during sysprep one would need to inject drivers? Is it necessary? Should I skip injecting drivers during sysprep? Or would it be faster to inject the drivers after sysprepping it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following what you're asking. You inject the driver into the offline image, it has nothing to do with sysprep.

Comment: during the capture process from the MDT sequence, it will inject drivers into the sysprepped image, why would you need that? I know you can prevent it from doing that simply by unchecking it, but why would you need to inject the drivers into the sysprepped image? Thanks!

Comment: That's a completely separate question than what you've originally asked here. Consider actually asking a second question on the site rather than in comments.